# Command pbxcp fails Xcode build

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem. I've downloaded project from svn and after build I've got this error message:

```
Command /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp failed with exit code 1
```

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 12):

Check the "Copy bundle resources" build stage to see if there are any missing files (png, txt, plist, etc.)